# Putting the title first in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing a publication list, and I'm using `\fullcite` to put the bib entries in the body.  Since this is a list of my publications, I would like to put the title first (I presume that the reader will be more interested in the title than in the author repeated again and again).  I can't seem to find a bibliography style which does this, and there wasn't an option with latex `makebst`.  A minimal non-working sample text is included below.  How can I put the title before the author?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{test1,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach,
               Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year      = {1994},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\nobibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{test1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since you are using `biblatex` you can't use makebst, also you shouldn't need `bibentry`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like

```
\AtNextCite{\def\do#1{\togglefalse{blx@use#1}}\dolistcsloop{blx@datamodel@names}}
\fullcite{companion}
```

For more involved use it is better to define a few auxiliary macros

```
\newcommand{\nameuse}[1]{%
  \def\do##1{\settoggle{blx@use##1}{#1}}%
  \dolistcsloop{blx@datamodel@names}}

\newcommand{\nameusesave}{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \providetoggle{blx@save@use##1}%
    \iftoggle{blx@use##1}{\toggletrue{blx@save@use##1}}{\togglefalse{blx@save@use##1}}%
  }%
  \dolistcsloop{blx@datamodel@names}}

\newcommand{\nameuserestore}{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \iftoggle{blx@save@use##1}{\toggletrue{blx@use##1}}{\togglefalse{blx@use##1}}%
  }%
  \dolistcsloop{blx@datamodel@names}}
```

Then you can use

```
\nameusesave
\nameuse{false}
\fullcite{sigfridsson}
\nameuserestore
```

---

If you are writing a publication list, you might want to use `\printbibliography` with filtering (based on categories for example)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{mine}
\addtocategory{mine}{companion,sigfridsson}
\nocite{companion,sigfridsson}

\newcommand{\nameuse}[1]{%
  \def\do##1{\settoggle{blx@use##1}{#1}}%
  \dolistcsloop{blx@datamodel@names}}

\newcommand{\nameusesave}{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \providetoggle{blx@save@use##1}%
    \iftoggle{blx@use##1}{\toggletrue{blx@save@use##1}}{\togglefalse{blx@save@use##1}}%
  }%
  \dolistcsloop{blx@datamodel@names}}

\newcommand{\nameuserestore}{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \iftoggle{blx@save@use##1}{\toggletrue{blx@use##1}}{\togglefalse{blx@use##1}}%
  }%
  \dolistcsloop{blx@datamodel@names}}

\begin{document}
\nameusesave
\nameuse{false}
\printbibliography[category=mine]
\nameuserestore

\printbibliography[category=mine]
\end{document}
```

In the light of [Title first in bibliography, update needed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/389293/35864), this answer has been updated to work with newer versions of `biblatex`, see the version history for the earlier code.

Comment: Thanks; that works great!  For the block of citations, the two lones after the \fullcite are to reset the bibliography format, correct?

Comment: @Malcolm Yes, that was the idea, but it didn't actually restore the settings, it just went back to the defaults, the new (slightly longer) solution does a real restore.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a small example defining a custom citation command. At the moment, it works only for article entries, but I used it to generate a publication list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{dummy2017,
  title = {Formatting citations the way you want},
  volume = {113},
  number = {12},
  urldate = {2015-05-05},
  journal = {Nonexistant Review Letters},
  author = {Smith, John and Doe, John},
  year = {2017},
  pages = {214221},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Custom cite command with a newline for authors and journal
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{maintitle+title}
   \newline\nopunct\newblock
   \usebibmacro{author}
   \newline\nopunct\newblock
   \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}
  }
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

% Make the titles in bold
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{{\bf #1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\mycite{dummy2017}
\end{document}
```

[image]