# Title first in bibliography, update needed

Tags: biblatex, biber

When I try this example code from [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297087/putting-the-title-first-in-the-bibliography) I get a Latex error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{mine}
\addtocategory{mine}{companion,sigfridsson}
\nocite{companion,sigfridsson}

\newcommand{\nameuse}[1]{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \settoggle{blx@use##1}{#1}
  }%
  \dolistcsloop{blx@biber@datamodel@names}}

\newcommand{\nameusesave}{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \providetoggle{blx@save@use##1}%
    \iftoggle{blx@use##1}{\toggletrue{blx@save@use##1}}{\togglefalse{blx@save@use##1}}%
  }%
  \dolistcsloop{blx@biber@datamodel@names}}

\newcommand{\nameuserestore}{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \iftoggle{blx@save@use##1}{\toggletrue{blx@use##1}}{\togglefalse{blx@use##1}}%
  }%
  \dolistcsloop{blx@biber@datamodel@names}}

\begin{document}
\nameusesave
\nameuse{false}
\printbibliography[category=mine]
\nameuserestore

\printbibliography[category=mine]
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \blx@biber@datamodel@names 
l.30 \nameusesave
```

I assume the reason is that I am using a newer version of Biblatex/Biber/something else. Am using Pdftex, Biber version 2.7 and (I believe) Biblatex version 3.7.

Would be grateful if somebody could explain the problem and/or post new code.

Addition: any working solution to the problem would be fine, of course. It doesn't have to be the same as this previous answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while ago when BibTeX was declared a legacy backend, the `biblatex` core was rewritten and most mentions of Biber were removed from command names.
The datamodel names are now stored in `\blx@datamodel@names` and not in `\blx@biber@datamodel@names`. So we need to change all three `\dolistcsloop{blx@biber@datamodel@names}` to

```
\dolistcsloop{blx@datamodel@names}
```

I have updated my answer to [Putting the title first in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297087/35864) to use the new names.

In full

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{mine}
\addtocategory{mine}{companion,sigfridsson}
\nocite{companion,sigfridsson}

\newcommand{\nameuse}[1]{%
  \def\do##1{\settoggle{blx@use##1}{#1}}%
  \dolistcsloop{blx@datamodel@names}}

\newcommand{\nameusesave}{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \providetoggle{blx@save@use##1}%
    \iftoggle{blx@use##1}{\toggletrue{blx@save@use##1}}{\togglefalse{blx@save@use##1}}%
  }%
  \dolistcsloop{blx@datamodel@names}}

\newcommand{\nameuserestore}{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \iftoggle{blx@save@use##1}{\toggletrue{blx@use##1}}{\togglefalse{blx@use##1}}%
  }%
  \dolistcsloop{blx@datamodel@names}}

\begin{document}
\nameusesave
\nameuse{false}
\printbibliography[category=mine]
\nameuserestore

\printbibliography[category=mine]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you say how to modify the code so that it doesn't print the "By" between the title and the authors?

Comment: @nGlacTOwnS Try `\renewbibmacro*{byauthor}{\printnames[byauthor]{author}}`. If that doesn't help, I suggest you ask a new question with an MWE of what you have at the moment and a more detailed description of what you need.

Comment: that worked! Thanks a lot :)